# Returning value of next visible cell from structured table in a different sheet

Tags: excel, vba

On the sheet named "Data" I have an Excel Table.  This table has a variable number of rows, typically 20k to 30k.  Column A is "JobNo"

On the sheet named "Main" I have cell where I show the "JobNo".  That value starts as the first visible JobNo from the filtered table.

I have buttons for "Next Record".  When I click this button and run it's associated VBA code, I need that code to move the "Data" sheet's cell pointer to the next visible (filtered) value in column A.

I've tried several samples of code found here to find the first visible cell, and to move to the next visible cell, but most of them relied on "Activecell".  I need to move a "virtual" pointer to the next visible cell because that sheet, where the table is located is not visible and so the ActiveCell is not there.

This for example works to move the cell pointer to the next visible cell, but it only works if "Dat" sheet is selected:

```
Sub movetest()

  Sheets("Data").Range("A1").EntireColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Find(What:="*", After:=ActiveCell).Activate

End Sub
```

What I need is something that can do what the above line does, but do it to a sheet that is not selected.  Bonus to me if it was in structured table syntax.

I also tried to use some variant of this, which moves to the first visible cell, but only when the "Data" sheet is selected:

```
Range("Data[[#All],[PACEJob]]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Find _
(What:="*", After:=ActiveSheet.Range("Data[[#Headers],[PACEJob]]"), _
LookIn:=xlFormulas, lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

EDIT:

This does what I need for non filtered table.  Just need to replicate this to do the same thing with a filtered table and only show visible.

```
  (GLobal selectedRow)

  selectedJobRow = selectedJobRow + 1
  Sheets("Main").Range("O2").Value = Sheets("Data").Range("A" & selectedJobRow).Value
```

Comment: You can't select or activate a cell on a non-active sheet, not that you generally need to anyway.

Comment: I know.  That's my problem.  How to do it without using activecell

Answer (score 0):

I gave up trying to work around the sheet not being active and Activecell.  This seems to work, although it seems like there would be a more elegant way, No?

```
Sub movePointerDown()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set wksToCheck = Sheets("Data")
  Sheets("data").Select
  Sheets("Data").Range("A1").EntireColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Find(What:="*", After:=ActiveCell).Activate

  Sheets("Main").Range("O2").Value = ActiveCell.Value

  Sheets("Main").Select
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

And its companion:

```
Sub movePointerUp()

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Set wksToCheck = Sheets("Data")
  Sheets("data").Select
  Sheets("Data").Range("A1").EntireColumn.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Find(What:="*", After:=ActiveCell, Searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Activate

  Sheets("Main").Range("O2").Value = ActiveCell.Value

  Sheets("Main").Select
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't need to work with [ActiveCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.activecell) if you use [Excel objects](https://www.google.com/search?q=excel+vba+working+with+objects&rlz=1C1CHBF_enVE851VE851&oq=excel+vba+working+with+objects&aqs=chrome..69i57j33l5.14386j1j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), there is plenty of information about the subject on the internet.

This proposed solution returns the next `Cell` record, and it's wrapped in a [Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/function-statement)
 to allow for flexibility. It uses a [Static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/static-statement) variable to keep track of actual record *(see link provided for details)* and validates the `ListObject` (excel Table) field, its `AutoFilter` and whether the actual record is the last visible record.

```
Function ListObject_ƒNextVisibleCell(rOutput As Range, sMsgOut As String, sFld As String) As Boolean
Static rCll As Range
Const kMsg1 As String = "Field [ #FLD ] not found."
Const kMsg2 As String = "ListObject filter returned zero records"
Const kMsg3 As String = "Actual record is the last visible record"
Dim wsDATA As Worksheet
Dim lo As ListObject
Dim rTrg As Range
Dim rCllLast As Range

    Set wsDATA = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA")
    Set lo = wsDATA.ListObjects("lo.DATA")  'update as required

    With lo
        On Error Resume Next

        Rem Validate Field
        Set rTrg = .ListColumns(sFld).DataBodyRange
        If rTrg Is Nothing Then
            sMsgOut = Replace(kMsg1, "#FLD", sFld)
            Exit Function
        End If

        Rem Validate ListObject AutoFilter
        Set rTrg = Nothing
        Set rTrg = .ListColumns(sFld).DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If rTrg Is Nothing Then sMsgOut = kMsg2: Exit Function

        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    Select Case (rCll Is Nothing)

    Case True
        Rem No Previous Record
        Set rCll = rTrg.Cells(1)

    Case False
        With lo.ListColumns(sFld).DataBodyRange

            Rem Validate Last Record
            Set rCllLast = rTrg.Areas(rTrg.Areas.Count).Cells(rTrg.Areas(rTrg.Areas.Count).Cells.Count)
            If rCll.Address = rCllLast.Address Then
                sMsgOut = kMsg3
                Exit Function

            Else
                Rem Reset Visible Cells Range
                Set rTrg = Range(rCll.Offset(1), .Cells(.Cells.Count))
                Set rTrg = rTrg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

                Rem Set Next Record
                Set rCll = rTrg.Cells(1)

    End If: End With: End Select

    Rem Set Results
    Set rOutput = rCll
    ListObject_ƒNextVisibleCell = True

    End Function
```

It should be called in this manner

```
Sub ListObject_ƒNextVisibleCell_TEST()
Const kTitle As String = "ListObject Next Visible Cell"
Dim wsMain As Worksheet, rCll As Range
Dim sFld As String, sMsg As String

    sFld = "JobNo"
    Set wsMain = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Main")

    If ListObject_ƒNextVisibleCell(rCll, sMsg, sFld) Then
        wsMain.Range("O2").Value2 = rCll.Value2

    Else
        MsgBox sMsg, vbCritical, kTitle

    End If: End With

    End Sub
```

Suggest to check the following pages for details about the resources used:

[Worksheet object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet)
[ListObject object (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.listobject)
[Application.Range property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.range)
[With statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement)
[MsgBox function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/msgbox-function)